# Correct curvature tensor of symmetric space of positive definite matrices with trace metric?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, symmetric-spaces

Let $Pos(n)$ be the set of $n \times n$ real positive definite matrices with trace (aka affine-invariant) metric
$$\langle u, v \rangle_p = tr(p^{-1} u p^{-1} v)$$
for all $p \in Pos(n)$ and $u, v \in T_p Pos(n) \cong Sym(n)$.
Here $Sym(n)$ is the set of real symmetric $n \times n$ matrices, which we identify with the tangent spaces of $Pos(n)$.

In Chapter XII of *Fundamentals of Riemannian Geometry*, Serge Lang states that for $u, v, w \in T_I Pos(n) \cong Sym(n)$, the curvature tensor is given by
$$\langle R(v, w)v, w \rangle = -2 tr((v w)^2-v^2 w^2).$$
However, in papers online (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.01113.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4565.pdf)) Dolcetti et al. show that
$$\langle R(v, w)v, w \rangle = \frac{1}{4}(-2 tr((v w)^2-v^2 w^2)).$$
Note the factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ here.

Which expression for the curvature tensor is correct?

---

More context:
Dolcetti et al. compute the curvature tensor with fairly direct methods.  Lang uses the following approach.  There is one step of this approach I am uncertain of.

Let $M$ be a symmetric space with Riemannian connection $\nabla$.  Let $p \in M$ and define $m_p$ to be the set of Killing vector fields $X$ on $M$ with $(\nabla X)_p = 0$.
It is well-known that the map
$$m_p \rightarrow T_p M,  X \mapsto X_p$$
is a bijection.

Moreover, it is also well-known that the curvature tensor of $M$ is given by
$$R(U, V) W = [W, [U, V]].$$
for all $U, V, W \in m_p$.
Here $[\cdot, \cdot]$ denotes the Lie bracket.

For references, see
(1) Chapter XIII of Serge Lang's *Fundamentals of Riemannian Geometry*
or (2) Chapter 8 of Peter Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry*.

Using these facts, in the last theorem of Chapter XII, Lang gives a formula for curvature tensor of the space of positive definite matrices $Pos$ with the trace metric:
[image]

Here Lang seems to implicitly use that for $U, V, W \in m_p$,
$$[W, [U, V]] = [W_p, [U_p, V_p]_{com}]_{com}$$
where for matrices $A, B$ we have $[A, B]_{com} = A B - B A$ is the matrix commutator (not the Lie bracket).

It is not at all clear to me that this is true.
For example, if $U, V \in m_p$, it cannot be the case that $[U, V]_p = U_p V_p - V_p U_p$ because $U_p V_p - V_p U_p$ is not element of $T_p Pos(n) = Sym(n)$.

Comment: If $A, B$ are symmetric matrices, then the matrix commutator $[A,B]$ is antisymmetric. If $C$ is again symmetric, then $[C,[A,B]]$ is now symmetric. So the symmetry argument doesn't entirely rule out the formula from being true.

Comment: Can you check to see if the identification of $T_e\mathrm{Pos}(n)$ with $\mathrm{Sym}(n)$ by the authors agree? It is possible that there are hidden factors of 2 in how one represents an element of the tangent space with a symmetric matrix that would contribute to the multiplicative factor that shows up in the curvature tensor.

Comment: @WillieWong I agree that my symmetry argument doesn't entirely rule out the formula from being true.  To the best of my knowledge, both Lang and Dolcetti et al. identify tangent spaces with Sym(n) in the same way, and the metrics they put on those tangent spaces are exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% certain with this, but I think the following computations check out.

Let $x$ be an arbitrary symmetric matrix, then the vector field $X$ that takes value $\frac12(xM + Mx)$ at point $M\in \mathrm{Pos}(n)$ is Killing and satisfies $\nabla X |_{e} = 0$. (That it is Killing follows from the fact that it generates the one parameter family of isometries $\mathbb{R}\times \mathrm{Pos}(n) \ni (t,M) \mapsto \exp(\frac12 t x) M \exp(\frac12 tx)$. That it has vanishing covariant derivative at the identity can be checked using a local coordinate computation.)

Now let $X,Y,Z$ be the vector fields corresponding to $\frac12 (xM + Mx), \frac12 (yM + My), \frac12 (zM + Mz)$ respectively.
The Lie bracket
$$ [X,Y] = \frac14 (xyM + Myx - yxM - Mxy) $$
of course vanishes at the origin, and we find
$$ [[X,Y],Z] |_e = \frac14 ( xyz + zyx - yxz - zxy) = \frac14 ( [xy,z]_{\mathrm{com}} - [yx,z]_{\mathrm{com}}) = \frac14 [[x,y]_{\mathrm{com}},z]_{\mathrm{com}} $$
which would indicate that Lang omitted a factor of 1/4 when converting from the Lie bracket of vector fields to the representation using matrix commutators.

Answer (score 0):

This actually could be done directly from the operator form of usual formulas for Christoffel symbols and curvature by Einstein summation (same idea as writing $AB$ instead of $A^i_jB^j_k$).  Note that we are working on an open subset of the vector space $Sym(n)$. The formulas are:
$$\Gamma(v, w) = \frac{1}{2}g^{-1}(D_v gw + D_wgv - \chi_g(v, w)), \\
R(v,w)z = (D_v\Gamma)(w, z) - (D_w\Gamma)(v, z) + \Gamma(v, \Gamma(w, z)) - \Gamma(w, \Gamma(v, z)).
$$
Here, $g$ is the metric operator, $g(p)v = p^{-1}vp^{-1},g(p)^{-1}v = pvp
$ for this metric, $D$ is the directional derivative in the manifold variable $p$, so
$$D_vg w = -p^{-1} vp^{-1}wp^{-1} -p^{-1} wp^{-1}vp^{-1}.
$$
$\chi_g$ is the index raising term, the element in $Sym(n)$ such that $tr(\chi_g(v, w) z) = tr D_zgv. w$, and we can verify $\chi_g(v, w) = -p^{-1} vp^{-1}wp^{-1} -p^{-1} wp^{-1}vp^{-1}$ satisfies that condition.

Let $A_{sym} = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$,
$A_{skew} = \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)$. We can simplify to get the well-known formula
$$\Gamma(v, w) = -\frac{1}{2}(vp^{-1}w + wp^{-1}v) = - (vp^{-1}w)_{sym}.$$
The Riemannian curvature $R(v,w)z = (D_v\Gamma)(w, z) - (D_w\Gamma)(v, z) + \Gamma(v, \Gamma(w, z)) - \Gamma(w, \Gamma(v, z))
$ is
$$R(v, w)z = -(-wp^{-1}vp^{-1}z)_{sym} +(-vp^{-1}wp^{-1}z )_{sym}\\
+ (vp^{-1}(wp^{-1}z)_{sym})_{sym} - (wp^{-1}(vp^{-1}z)_{sym})_{sym}\\\
= (wp^{-1}(vp^{-1}z)_{skew})_{sym} - (vp^{-1}(wp^{-1}z)_{skew} )_{sym}\\
= \frac{1}{4}\{w(p^{-1}v p^{-1}z -p^{-1}z p^{-1}v)
+ (zp^{-1}v p^{-1} -vp^{-1}z p^{-1})w
- v(p^{-1}wp^{-1}z - p^{-1}zp^{-1}w)
-(zp^{-1}wp^{-1} - wp^{-1}zp^{-1})v\}
\\
= -\frac{1}{4}p[[p^{-1}v, p^{-1}w]_{com}p^{-1}z]_{com}$$
where the last simplification is similar to the Jacobi's identity, the terms with $p^{-1}z$ in the middle cancel.

The sectional curvature can be computed from here
$$R(v, w)w, v = -\frac{1}{4}tr ([[p^{-1}v, p^{-1}w]_{com}p^{-1}v]_{com}p^{-1}w)
= -\frac{1}{2}tr\{(p^{-1}vp^{-1}w)^2 - (p^{-1}v)^2(p^{-1}w)^2\}.
$$
The operator formula for the curvature applies for all embedded manifolds, even for affine connections. The formula for the Christoffel symbols needs some adjustment [1] if we are not in an open subset. The operator formula is useful even if we do not have simple cancelations: we can actually test a proposed curvature formula numerically. If we have a formula for $\Gamma$ implemented as a function, the directional derivatives can be computed easy using numerical differentiation, using [jax](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), for example. See the following references, the [github](https://github.com/dnguyend/EmbeddedGeometry) has several examples where the curvatures are calculated using jax, the Bianchi identities are verified numerically.

[1] Du Nguyen, Operator-Valued Formulas for Riemannian Gradient and Hessian and Families of Tractable Metrics in Riemannian Optimization, Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications (2023) 198:135–164, https://doi.org/10.1007/s10957-023-02242-z, read cube: https://rdcu.be/ddyWJ

[2] Du Nguyen, Geometry in global coordinates in mechanics and optimal transport. https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.10017